# How to save data from another Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, save

I need to save an the following data: appointment Time, Date, who is Appointment is with. I have a activity called "Appointment Filters" where user selects a Person, Time and Date and Confirm that with a button click. What I want to do is save that data in another activity called "My appointments". I wanted to save it to a listview. Whenever user creates an appointment it get saved to the list and whenever the appointment time is up, it removes itself. I also wanted the data to be editable. Is this possible in android? I looked up Shared Preferences but I do not think it is possible with that.

Comment: You could centralize your data so that all your activities have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the issue, i will definitely recommend to use SQLite database for the data manipulation. [Hear is nice tutorial how to implment SQLite.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Oleg suggested, use Sqlite and u should. 
but if u dont want to use it for some reason, u can still use Shared Preferences, All Appointmenent details can be stored as CSV and have an id for it Eg.

`id:1, Value:My appt1, 9:30am, 10:30am`

`id:2, Value:My appt1, 10:35am, 12:30pm`

then u can store it as 
putString(String key, String value)

To retrieve at any point, u can use getAll and iterate over the returned map. But Sqlite is the way to go in long run.